# RelativeLayout: layout_alignWithParentIfMissing not working

Tags: android

I am having a `RelativeLayout` with two `TextView` objects. I want `@+id/b` to move up if `@+id/a` is missing.

I therefore tried to set the content `null` when I inflate the parent view but all what happens is that there is just no text displayed. `@+id/b` remains on its place and `@+id/a` is still there - without text.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...
    holder.a.setText(null);
    //parent.removeView(holder.a)               // Did not work
    //holder.a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   // Did not work
    // ...
}
```

I've also tried to remove with `parent.removeView(holder.a)` resulting in a first class app-crash.

Where did I go wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/a"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide `@+id/a`, why don't you just `setVisibility(View.GONE)`?

Comment: It's not about the visibility. It's about `@+id/b` should move up if `@+id/a` is removed, invisible or empty.

Comment: And you have tried two methods to remove `a` but none of them worked.. BTW is there a reason to use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Afaik you have to use `RelativeLayout` for such a thing as it offers attributes like `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` that are supposed to do what I am asking for.

Comment: that is correct. But if you have `b` set below `a` and you set `a` `visibility:gone` then `b` will be aligned to the top of the layout even without `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing`.

Comment: Works! :) Who needs `RelativeLayout` anyway. Thanks

Comment: Well this solution worhs with both layouts. I personally prefer to use `RelativeLayout` since it's very powerful but in this case using a `LinearLayout` is computationally faster. Glad I helped you :)